# LINQ Query Using Navigation Properties Generates Multiple SELECT Statements

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a POCO Domain Entity class that contains convenience methods to navigate to related records.  I am using the AdventureWorks2008R2 database to demonstrate what I am attempting to accomplish.  All of these queries can be run in LINQPad to observe the SQL statements generated.

```cs
SalesOrderHeaders.Where(s => s.SalesOrderID == 43659)
                 .Single().SalesOrderDetails
```

This statement produces 2 SQL statements.  One for the SalesOrderHeader record and one to retrieve the SalesOrderDetails.  Now consider this statement that navigates to an additional related table:

```cs
SalesOrderHeaders.Where(s => s.SalesOrderID == 43659)
                 .Single().SalesOrderDetails.Select(s => s.SpecialOfferProduct)
```

After retrieving a single SalesOrderHeader record, the domain class would contain a convenience property like this:

```cs
public IQueryable<SpecialOfferProduct> SpecialProducts
    {
        get
        {
            return SalesOrderDetails.Where(sod => sod.OrderQty > 3)
                                    .Select(s => s.SpecialOfferProduct)
                                    .AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

This statement produces multiple SELECT statements: one for each record in SpecialOfferProduct.  My question is: why don't the navigation properties produce a single SELECT statement?  This is a huge performance issue because it generates a lot of unnecessary chatter.  I could use LINQ SQL syntax, but that is only when making the original query using the Repository.  In this case I have an instance of a SalesOrderHeader object and don't have access to the Context or the Repository inside the class.  Is there way to force it to create a single SELECT statement using JOINs?

If there is not a way to do it I was thinking of creating an additional method in my Repository to populate these properties.  The problem is then I have 2 steps: 1 to retrieve the SalesOrderHeader object, then another to populate the additional properties using the appropriate LINQ statement that would force the JOIN syntax.

Comment: You have lazy loading set to true. Set it to false or use `Include` method to eagerly load navigation property entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment you need the [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method:

```
SalesOrderHeaders.Include(s => s.SalesOrderDetails
                                .Select(d => d.SpecialOfferProduct))
                 .Where(s => s.SalesOrderID == 43659)
                 .Single().SalesOrderDetails
```

this will join the required data (in SQL) and populate the navigation properties.

Note, however, that you can't use syntax like

```
.Include(s => s.SalesOrderDetails.Where(sod => sod.OrderQty > 3)
               .Select(d => d.SpecialOfferProduct))
```

Which seemingly would partly populate `SalesOrderDetails`. There are change requests to the EF team to implement this, but so far, this hasn't been done.

Another side note is that it's useless to return `SpecialProducts` as `IQueryable` because subsequent queries on the collection won't get translated to SQL anyway. You can only access the property in in-memory statements in the first place, not in linq-to-enitites queries (EF cant translate the property into SQL).